# Java connection to Powermta

Tags: jakarta-mail, java, powermta, pmta

I want to send mails from Powermta server with java program, I want to know if exist some java api to connect it, I use Java Mail to send mails,  but if Powermta cannot send some email there not get any response.

any idea?

Comment: PowerMTA ships with a Java API. Did you check that?

Comment: Did you found pmta.jar file? I am also looking for it.

Answer (score 1):

> but if Powermta cannot send some email there not get any response.

What do you mean by this? backoff? you can use backoff-notify in PowerMTA configuration.

PowerMTA supports SMTP injection and probably it is the easiest method as it is standard SMTP negotiations supported by almost all programming languages that are being used today.